# Do action when clicking in a TreePanel node

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, ext.net

**Current Status:**
I have a TreePanel and a GridPanel, where the former loads categories and the second articles, both from a database.
Using Visual Studio 2010, Ext.Net 2.5 and C#

**The problem:**
I'm not being able to make it so when you click in a category (TreePanel node), it does a certain function (in my case I want to fill the articles based on what category was clicked, as the nodes have ID)

I tried to use TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs but it didn't work (in fact it created a class that has nothing), and since I just started to use this software (and language), I'm stuck.

Thanks a lot in advance.

**Edit**
The last code I tried was [from MS website.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.nodemousedoubleclick(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Post the code that didn't work in order to get help.  Update the tags with the platform you are programming against (ASP?  WinForms?  WPF?)

Comment: Done (Thanks!). It is a ASP.NET website using the EXT.NET 2.5 component framework

Comment: Clearly the code from the MS website works, but we don't know why it doesn't work for you.  That code was for the WinForms version, by the way.

Comment: So I need to look for something that works in ASP.

Comment: As someone who doesn't have experience with the platform, I'm glad that I decided to ask otherwise I would have lost a lot of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way, and will share it:

**On client side**
*After adding the treepanel, add a DirectEvents*

```
<DirectEvents>
    //Calls a function when doing click on a node
    <ItemClick OnEvent="yourFunction">
        <ExtraParams>
            //Loads the nodeID
            <ext:Parameter Name="NodeID" Value="record.data.id" Mode="Raw"/>
        </ExtraParams>
    </ItemClick>
</DirectEvents>
```

**On server side**

```
public void yourFunction(object sender, DirectEventArgs e)
{
    //Ask the nodeID
    string id = e.ExtraParams["NodeID"];
    //Your function goes below
}
```